# Program for speed reading. Is it possible to highlight a word in the text that is displayed in the window?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Is it possible to somehow highlight a word in my program (one and the other with the same) in a different color. I thought about making a canvas in a canvas, but it didn’t work out.

```
class Application(object):

     def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg='black')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas_text = self.canvas.create_text(180, 130, text='',anchor=tk.NW,fill="white",font=('Arial',18))


        self.entry = tk.Entry(root)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.entry_cb)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus()
        root.mainloop()
     def animate_text(self, text, delta):
        delay = 0
        for i in range(len(text)+1):
            update_text = lambda s=text[i - 1:-1]: self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.canvas_text, text=s)
            self.canvas.after(delay, update_text)
            delay += delta


     def entry_cb(self, event):
       # s = self.entry.get().split()
        s = 'London is the capital of Great Britain'.split()
        s += [s[-1]]
        self.animate_text(s, skorost)

skorost = 400

app = Application()
```

Comment: "…highlight a word in the text"? What text? What kind of widget is it in? Please provide a [mre] with an emphasis on "minimal" meaning without any code unrelated to the problem in it — and more precisely describe what it is you want to do.

Comment: the text that is served in the entry_sb. in it I need to highlight the word in a different color. what can be done for this